# I want to call private sub from worksheet in excel and the value should change in sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

My query is if I insert row using a button, it should also add serial numbers to the rows like 1,2,3 etc...

I have the below code here in Sheet1 of the worksheet for adding the serial numbers when I add rows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim StartNum As Integer
    Dim FirstCell As Integer
    Dim LastCell As Integer

    StartNum = 2
    FirstCell = 3
    LastCell = 17

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Do While FirstCell <= LastCell
        Range("B" & FirstCell).Value = StartNum
        FirstCell = FirstCell + 1
        StartNum = StartNum + 1
    Loop
    Range("B" & LastCell + 1).Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The below code is written in module1 to insert rows with formula of A1 copied to new rows

```
Sub Macro2()
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B1:D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:D2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B1:D2").Select
End Sub
```

Now my Question is how to call the private sub from the Module Macro2 code while inserting rows

Any suggestions, waiting for your replies at the earliest.

Comment: You don't need worksheet change event, you can achieve that in your macro itself...

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned you do not need the `Worksheet_Change` code for this. Paste the below code in a module and try it..

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Insert at row 2
        .Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        '~~> Autofill B1:D1 to C1:D2
        .Range("B1:D1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B1:D2"), Type:=xlFillDefault

        '~~> Find the last row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=.Range("A1"), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        '~~> Renumber the cells in Col B
        For i = 1 To lRow
            .Range("B" & i).Value = i
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Double

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Insert at row 2
        .Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        '~~> Autofill B1:D1 to C1:D2
        .Range("B1:D1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B1:D2"), Type:=xlFillDefault

        '~~> Find the last row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=.Range("A1"), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        '~~> Renumber the cells in Col B 1,1.1,1.2,1.3 etc
        j = 1

        For i = 1 To lRow
            .Range("B" & i).Value = j
            j = j + 0.1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddhath however am bit new to VBA, hence i do not understand the code, could you please explain what this code will do..?

Comment: I have commented the above code so that you shouldn't have any problem understanding it :)

Comment: Are you still facing problems?

Comment: Thanks for your code, however i would like to add the serial number in this series 1.1,1.2,1.3 is it possible ?

Comment: That was not what you originally wanted?

Comment: Well that is the solution I was looking for, I want to add the values in 1.1.,1.2 series

Comment: Could you please tell me which part of your question mentions that? :) All I can see is `My query is if I insert row using a button, it should also add serial numbers to the rows like 1,2,3 etc...` for which I have already given you a solution...

Comment: Also Siddharth Iam overwhelmed by your instant response, and also if i delete any rows in between the series and the Autofilled formula should continue as per previous row value, whether this functionality can be added ?

Comment: Initially my query was with 1,2,3 series however due to new amendments I have to stick to 1.1,1.2 series is it possible in amending the for Loop code.

Comment: Everytime you run the macro `after` deleting the rows, the code will autonumber the rows. The code below `'~~> Renumber the cells in Col B` line takes care of that. See the followup in the above post. I have updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for the code its working flawlessly, and its a fantastic code till now for me in this forum, however if there is any formulas like I have a formula which is validating some cells using =IF(ISBLANK($E154);;HLOOKUP($F154;CONS;2;FALSE)*HLOOKUP($E154;PROB;2;FALSE)) which will color some cells based on range values, whether this formula can be copied down, To be precise I want the formula also to be copied based on cell values till the end is it possible ?